# docker-compose ignores installed django, virtualenv

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, mod-wsgi

docker-compose ignores installed virtual environment

I am trying to dockerize my existing django app. Also I am new to docker, so please forgive me, if this is some sort of "just read the instructions" thing. Question 51490937 seems to be somewhat related, but I am not sure about that. My app runs apache with a pip install mod-wsgi and it already deploys well to a native ubuntu 18 and 19 vm. 
I run win10 and I am using a linux container with Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5 and I run a python:3.7 base image.

My problem: Running my installed image fails when I use docker-compose up, but succeeds when I run the same  manually. I first assumed, I have a caching problem, but trying all the things as suggested by https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-cache/5753 did not help.  Also the time stamp of my local project folder is identical to the time stamp of the manually run container and the one returned by the Dockerfile.  So now I assume there is something wrong with my docker-compose.yml, or I activated some branching, that I am not aware of. (files are attached at the end) For debugging I removed the postgress service and now run the default sqlite db.

`docker-compose up (ls -la && source venv/bin/activate)` returns:

```
some other files...
302_game_container | -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   400 Nov 11 16:49 test.py
302_game_container | drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     0 Nov 12 11:55 web_project
302_game_container | bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory <---- The ERROR
302_game_container exited with code 1
```

Note: The time stamp shown here is (11:55 web_project) and venv folder is missing. It looks like the venv was not properly installed.

However, when I now run the same image manually, by typing:

```
docker run -it -d 302_chess_game_2019_11_12_15_20_33_354574

docker exec -it myDockerContainer bash

ls -la && source venv/bin/activate
```

I get the desired result:

```
some other files...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       400 Nov 11 16:49 test.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Nov 12 11:57 venv
drwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data  4096 Nov 12 11:59 web_project
(venv) root@d98fde4a6316:/302_chess_game#
```

I can then successfully run python web_project/manage.py runserver and even sudo /etc/wsgi-port-8000/apachectl restart. So the image contains the installed venv. I can then view the page under 0.0.0.0:8000.

my setup:
The Dockerfile runs a script.sh which installs all prod programs, creates my venv, installs requirements.txt, activates the venv and then RUNs makemigrations, migrate and collectstatic. All tasks run successfully. The last step in 
`Dockerfile RUNs ls -la` returns:

```
some other files...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       400 Nov 11 16:49 test.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Nov 12 11:57 venv
drwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data  4096 Nov 12 11:59 web_project
```

As you can see, the venv is installed inside the image and the time stamp for the web_project folder is (11:59 web_project).

Here is my reduced `docker-compose.yml` (project=302_chess_game, timeStamp=_2019_11_12_15_20_33_354574, port=8000, image=python:3.7)

```
version: '3'
services:
    python:
        image: {{ project }}{{ timeStamp }}
        container_name: 302_game_container
        volumes:
            - .:/{{ project }}
        ports:
            - {{ port }}:{{ port }}
        command: >
            bash -c "ls -la && source venv/bin/activate"
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM {{ image }}

# install ubuntu stuff
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install sudo

# copy files
RUN sudo mkdir /{{ project }}
WORKDIR /{{ project }}
COPY . /{{ project }}/

# set default evn variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# set environment variables
ENV PORT={{ port }}
ENV PRODUCTION=1
ENV SERVER={{ server }}
ENV DEBUG={{ debug }}
ENV DATABASE={{ database }}

# install shell script
RUN chmod 777 ./resources/{{ install_sh }}
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./resources/{{ install_sh }}
RUN ./resources/{{ install_sh }}
RUN ls -la

EXPOSE {{ port }}
# add user implemented later
#RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash {{ username }}
#RUN echo '{{ username }}:test321' | chpasswd
#RUN adduser {{ username }} sudo
#RUN chown -R {{ username }}:sudo /{{ project }}
#USER {{ username }}
```

Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt install vim -y
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev -y
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo apt install apache2-dev -y
sudo apt install -y python3-venv
pip3 install mod_wsgi
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install mod_wsgi
sudo mkdir /etc/wsgi-port-{{ port }}
sudo chown -R {{ username }}:{{ username }} /etc/wsgi-port-{{ port }}
sudo groupadd  www-data
sudo adduser  www-data  www-data
sudo chown -R :www-data web_project/media/
sudo chmod -R 775 web_project/media/
sudo chown -R :www-data web_project
sudo chmod 777 web_project
sudo chown :www-data web_project/{{ project }}.sqlite3
sudo chmod 664 web_project/{{ project }}.sqlite3
python web_project/manage.py makemigrations
python web_project/manage.py migrate
python web_project/manage.py collectstatic
python web_project/manage.py runmodwsgi --server-root /etc/wsgi-port-{{ port }} --user www-data --group www-data --port {{ port }} --url-alias /static static --url-alias /media media --setup-only
#
# sudo cp conf_files/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# sudo systemctl restart sshd
# sudo apt install ufw -y
# sudo ufw default allow outgoing
# sudo ufw default deny incoming
# sudo ufw allow ssh
# sudo ufw allow http/tcp
# sudo ufw allow https/tcp
# sudo ufw allow 3389
# sudo ufw enable
# sudo passwd {{ username }}
# netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
# sudo ufw status
# sudo /etc/wsgi-port-{{ port }}/apachectl restart
# sudo apt install xrdp
# sudo apt remove lightdm
# sudo apt install xfce4
# sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal tango-icon-theme
# echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession
# sudo apt install libexo-1-0
# sudo apt install firefox
# sudo service xrdp restart
# sudo /etc/wsgi-port-{{ port }}/apachectl restart
```

To reproduce run the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    python:
        image: lmielke/302_chess_game_2019_11_12_15_49_04_892687:testcontainer
        container_name: 302_game_container
        volumes:
            - .:/302_chess_game
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        command: >
            bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && 
            sudo apachectl stop && 
            sudo /etc/wsgi-port-8000/apachectl start"
```

This will pull the image but container build will fail as described. Then run:

```
docker run -it -d (imgId), 
docker exec -it (containerId), 
source venv/bin/activate, 
sudo /etc/wsgi-port-8000/apachectl start,
```

It will show some alias warning but run ok. You can add `ls -la` to the bash cmds to see that there is no venv folder.

Comment: Can you cut this down to a [mcve]?  You don’t generally need a virtual environment in Docker (the container itself provides isolation) and that seems like it addresses the core of your issues.  You also don’t generally need `sudo`, but your Dockerfile does need a `CMD` instruction to tell the container how to run the application.

Comment: see if you can adapt this: https://gitlab.com/komalbarun/basic-docker-django-nginx-uwsgi/tree/master/ ?

Comment: @David: Your are right, I will optimize the install ones its running. As for the CMD instruction, I was hoping to use the docker-compose.yml command tag to do this. The third command there would be sudo /etc/wsgi-port-8000/apachectl restart but since i did not even make it there, I left it out of the example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so eventually it was a no brainer. I intended to activate the venv within my image project folder, which is of cause challenging, when beforehand I mount my local folder within docker-compose.